# How to "jump to source" in vscode on mac?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am switching from webstorm to vscode. I cannot figure out how to jump to source from explorer view? more details below.

1. when I want to select files in project folder, I will press "command + shift + E", which will activate explore window;
2. move cursor to select the file I want to view/edit;
3. In webstorm I can press F4 to jump to source, but in VSCode I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in Finder on the Mac, cmd+down will open the file you've selected in the explorer.

Comment: As an alternate, you could also use this extension [Reveal](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=smulyono.reveal) which updates the VS code's UI by putting a reveal in explorer button. Here are some **[recommended extensions](https://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/moving-from-webstorm-phpstorm-to-vs-code/)** for VS code